# jqueryui button click not working with url.action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am using a jqueryui button in my shared/_layout.cshtml for the login button. Below is the code for the click event. On clicking the button, I want the user to be transferred to the Logon view of the Account controller.

```
    $("#btnSignIn").click(function () {
            //alert("This is button on click event.");
            top.location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Logon", "Account"); %>'
        });
```

When debugging, I get the following error. I have looked around in SO for help for this.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is strange. If it's your `_layout.cshtml`, then you are using Razor.

For Razor, it should be:

```
$("#btnSignIn").click(function () {
        //alert("This is button on click event.");
        top.location.href = '@Url.Action("Logon", "Account")';
 });
```

Comment: I am quite new to MVC, still working my way around with the syntaxes. Thanks your solution worked.